# Publish Content From Another Authoritative Site

Tags: site, replication

Ok SharePoint Geniuses...

Here's what I got.  I have two corporate offices, both connected to each other via VPN.  Offices have different functions but occasionally are needing to access data at the other office(s).

What I would like to do is have separate content authored at each office but have the content from each replicated to the other. So data "A" would be created at office 1 and replicated to office 2 and data "B" would be created at office 2 and replicated to office 1.  So the offices would have access to the other offices information locally but that server not be authoritative.

So I dont want true bidirectional replication because office 1 should not be able to alter office 2's data "B" and vice versa.

So the easiest solution would be to just create two completely different SP deployments and put a replica of each in the other office.  But ideally I would like to have them integrated.  And I would like to avoid the 3rd party option...

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of replication content across different location in some sort of read-only mode, why don’t you use a single farm over WAN? It’s well supported in SharePoint 2013 and you don’t have to worry about replicating content (that may or may not be read).

If you use WAN and a single farm (depending on the size of the organization) you could implement BranchCache. This will allow for local caching of files that are actually used by several users, and could work better than loading all content across different geographic locations.

> In a geographically distributed SharePoint Server 2013 environment, BranchCache can optimize WAN performance by caching large files that users download from SharePoint Server 2013.

Reference: [Global architectures for SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg441255.aspx)

When you have everything accessible in one farm on two different locations you can control read permission level and contribute permission level like you usually do in your SharePoint environment.

[image]